# Get table row with a "let"

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the row of a table by selecting a radio button.

And I want to get the line selected to then be able to get the experiment id of the selected one, but it tells me "Row index is: undefined" in the alert..
I got the code from : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tr_rowindex

I tried :

```js
displayRadioValue(int: any, x: any) {
  if (int == 1) {
    alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="experiments" matSort style="margin-bottom: 1%">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="experiment_id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Experiment ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let experiment"> {{experiment.experiment_id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-->And others parameters displayed
  <-->

    <ng-container matColumnDef="compare">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Compare </th>
      <!--<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let protocol"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></td>-->
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let experiment" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <button mdcIconButton [on]="true">
      <mdc-icon mdcIconOn (click)="displayRadioValue(1, this)">radio_button_unchecked</mdc-icon>
      <mdc-icon (click)="displayRadioValue(2)">radio_button_checked</mdc-icon>
    </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: Show `experiments` with some data

Comment: Try printing `this` to the console and see what it actually is. Spoiler: it is now table row.

Comment: Thank you mplungjan ! 
Adrita : I didn't put much datas on purpose to have a short demand, I just put the id to show an exemple, but there are others like name etc. These datas are stored in the backend, and the table is implemented with the let, so for exemple at the moment it has 8 lines
@Bluddymarri : actually no, I tried, it shows me the same description no matter which I select

Comment: I am sorry i dont understand your question, maybe u can clearify it  a bit . If you want to get the index of the table row you can do something like `*matCellDef="let experiment; let i = index"`

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear enough, on each new line I have a radio button, and I want to take the experiment_id of the line I selected by the radio button, I'll select many and the goal is to compare datas. So I need to take the row number when the radio button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

in a mat table you can use let row and row.position in a td alone don't forget add to displayColumns:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['row','position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];

  <ng-container matColumnDef="row">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  ...
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

If you want to use in a td together an element, define let element;let row

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let row"> 
        {{element.position}}{{row.position}} 
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  ...
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```